# @NamedNativeQuery and @SqlResultSetMapping: No converter found capable of converting from type [$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap]

Tags: spring-data-jpa, converters, named-query, sqlresultsetmapping

## I am getting the following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.test.repository.models.customs.LightAssetWithQtyDto]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
[...]
```

## My classes are the following:

### AssetEntity

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "LightAssetWithQtyDtoMapping",
        classes = {@ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = LightAssetWithQtyDto.class,
                columns = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Integer.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "stock_symbol", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "total", type = BigDecimal.class)
                })}
)
@NamedNativeQueries(
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = "AssetEntity.findAllAssetsWithQty",
                resultSetMapping = "LightAssetWithQtyDtoMapping",
                query = "SELECT a.id, a.stock_symbol, sum(t.quantity) AS total " +
                        "FROM asset a " +
                        "RIGHT JOIN \"transaction\" t ON a.id = t.asset_id " +
                        "GROUP BY a.stock_symbol, a.id HAVING sum(t.quantity) > 0"
        )
)
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "asset")
public class AssetEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    [...]
```

### LightAssetWithQtyDto

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class LightAssetWithQtyDto {
    private Integer id;

    private String stockSymbol;

    private BigDecimal total;

    public LightAssetWithQtyDto(Integer id, String stockSymbol, BigDecimal total) {
        this.id = id;
        this.stockSymbol = stockSymbol;
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

### AssetRepository

```
@Repository
public interface AssetRepository extends CrudRepository<AssetEntity, Integer> {
    List<LightAssetWithQtyDto> findAllAssetsWithQty();
}
```

The @ConstructorResult seems to match the LightAssetWithQtyDto constructor.
Does anyone know where the error might have come from ^^' ??

I'm expecting findAllAssetsWithQty to return a List. Instead, I obtained an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Repository
public interface AssetRepository extends CrudRepository<AssetEntity, Integer> {
    @Query(name = "AssetEntity.findAllAssetsWithQty", nativeQuery = true)
    List<LightAssetWithQtyDto> findAllAssetsWithQty();
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.
Michael's answer is correct, but as I can't upvote it yet, I'll leave some precisions for future readers.

Doesn't work:

```
@Repository
public interface AssetRepository extends CrudRepository<AssetEntity, Integer> {
    List<LightAssetWithQtyDto> findAllAssetsWithQty();
}
```

Works :

```
@Repository
public interface AssetRepository extends CrudRepository<AssetEntity, Integer> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    List<LightAssetWithQtyDto> findAllAssetsWithQty();
}
```

Only the "NativeQuery=true" part is needed. I believe if you don't specify the query as Hibernate incorrectly flags the query as non native and thus ignores the SqlResultSetMapping.